# Finding inheritance property of a matlab class method

Tags: matlab, oop

How can I find out whether a property is inherited from a super class or is defined in the class definition directly?  Assuming `obj` is an instance of the class, I have tried:

```
properties(obj)
metaclass(obj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`metaclass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html) returns a [`meta.class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html) object that contains information about the class that is queried. The useful property of this `meta.class` object is the `PropertyList`, which contains information about all the properties of the class, including the `DefiningClass`.

Using the following class definitions as an example:

```
classdef asuperclass
    properties
        thesuperproperty
    end
end
```

and

```
classdef aclass < asuperclass
    properties
        theclassproperty
    end
end
```

We can now query the properties of `aclass` to determine where they came from:

```
tmp = ?aclass;
fprintf('Class Properties: %s, %s\n', tmp.PropertyList.Name)
fprintf('''theclassproperty'' defined by: %s\n', tmp.PropertyList(1).DefiningClass.Name)
fprintf('''thesuperproperty'' defined by: %s\n', tmp.PropertyList(2).DefiningClass.Name)
```

Which returns:

```
Class Properties: theclassproperty, thesuperproperty
'theclassproperty' defined by: aclass
'thesuperproperty' defined by: asuperclass
```

---

You can wrap this into a simple helper function. For example:

```
function classStr = definedby(obj, queryproperty)
tmp = metaclass(obj);
idx = find(ismember({tmp.PropertyList.Name}, queryproperty), 1);  % Only find first match

% Simple error check
if idx
    classStr = tmp.PropertyList(idx).DefiningClass.Name;
else
    error('Property ''%s'' is not a valid property of %s', queryproperty, tmp.Name)
end
end
```